# c++: неопределённый тип при наследовании

Tags: c++, наследование, итераторы

Подскажите, как разрешить следующую ситуацию - у меня есть базовый контейнер от которого наследуется 2 различных:

```
class IExtractorBase;
class CExtractor : public IExtractorBase;
class CExtracted_threaded: public IExtractorBase;
```

У `CExtractor` и `CExtracted_threaded` различаются итераторы (опять же разные классы), но хотелось бы в базовом классе сделать чистые виртуальные функции

```
virtual iterator        begin() = 0;
virtual iterator        end() = 0;

virtual const_iterator  cbegin() const = 0;
virtual const_iterator  cend() const = 0;
```

но сами типы разные для наследуемых классов

Как лучше всего обойти проблему?

Вижу 2 пути

1) сделать базовый класс шаблонным, чтобы можно было указывать что за класс будет итератором и константным итератором

2) можно вообще не делать абстрактный класс

Мне кажется, что первый вариант лучше. Или есть более хорошие решения?

Comment: Базовый класс может возвращать абстрактного предка обоих итераторов

Comment: да, но использовать во всяких for тогда не получится :)